# Organize table data by columns

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a django template that passes in two lists of varying sizes (but at least one item each).  I'm trying to display this data in a table so it looks like this:

```
List A | List B
-------------------
A - 1  | B - 1
A - 2  | B - 2
A - 3  | 
A - 4  |
```

(The empty cells in B could be empty, or something like '--')

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  Am I missing something obvious?

(Note:  I'm not the one who wants this as a table; I had it as two nice lists and it looked perfect, but I was overruled--I'm stuck with a table.)

EDIT:
So I'm iterating over each list with a django for loop.  I'm looking for something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>List A</th>
    <th>List B</th>
  </tr>

#first column
{% for person in listA %}
  <td>person</td>
{% endfor %}

#second column

{% for person in listB %}
  <td>person</td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure about what? The HTML? The lists? The template language?

Comment: The html.  Edited--please let me know if still unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your context define `records` using izip_longest to zip both lists.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listB = [1, 2, '--']

records = izip_longest(listA, listB)
# will return [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, '--'), (4, None)]
```

Later on your template do.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
    <tr>
    {% for col1, col2 in records %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{col1}}</td>
        <td>{{col2}}</td>
    <tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

See it working here http://djangotemplator.appspot.com/t/68342edf5d964872a0743a6a6183ef56/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  Templator also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full answer:
First, let's fix the context:

```
if len(a) <= len(b):
    a += ['-', ] * (len(b) - len(a))
else:
    b += ['-', ] * (len(a) - len(b))

my_composite_list = zip(a, b)
```

EDIT: - You can use itertools for this -

```
my_composite_list = izip_longest(a, b)
```

And we pass it to the context.

Then, in the template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List A</th>
            <th>List B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for a, b in my_composite_list %}
            <tr>
                 <td>{{ a }}</td><td>{{ b }}</td>
            </tr>              
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```